# MediaWiki: Is it possible to restrict view access to a certain page, an uploaded file or a namespace?

Tags: mediawiki, publishing

As my wiki is public and freely accessible worldwide, sometimes there is a need of not publishing some content before a certain event (let's say, a certain date). Let's say, I would like to upload a few files and keep them secret, however, I would like the content to be accessible to some super user groups. If I'm right, there is an extension Hidden Pages, but, from what I remember, it's more like a hack, and I wouldn't like to hide pages or files, but just restrict the view access. An example scenario I currently thinking of is as follows:

- Create a restricted namespace
- Upload a file into that namespace (as far as I remember, this is not possible in MediaWiki, though)
- Do not link a file from elsewhere but a page that's in a restricted namespace as well, so it couldn't be leaked
- Once a file could be published, just move a file (or a page) to an unrestricted namespace.

Is it possible in MediaWiki somehow?

Comment: Almost everything related to read restrictions in MediaWiki is a hack; the software was designed to be radically transparent. You can try e.g. [Extension:Blacklist](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Blacklist) but you should assume that a dedicated attacker can work around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Page_specific_user_rights_extensions) should help to find your needed extension.

These 3 extensions seem to get the job done:

- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Access_Control_List
- http://wiki.4intra.net/IntraACL
- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:NSFileRepo (this specially for administration of namespace related uploads)

Comment: Very nice options. I hope to test them soon.